# Inbuffer emacs calculation

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to do inbuffer calculation in emacs.

For example, if my file has the following numbers

10
11
12

(A) I would like to convert these numbers to hex (either in place or paste it next to that),

10  A
11  B
12  C

(B) I would like to sum those numbers.

10
11
12

33

(C) I would like to increment the count (sth like an index)

10
11
12
13
14

Comment: For (B) (the sum along a column of numbers) you can make a rectangular selection around your terms (`C-x SPC`, expand with the arrow keys) and then hit `C-x * :`. `q` closes the buffer with the result.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the inbuilt calculator and/or the fact that `\,` in the replacement string for commands like `replace-regexp` will evaluate an arbitrary elisp expression.

More-or-less of the top of my head you can do:

**A.**

1. Mark the region containing the numbers.
2. Execute <kbd>M-x replace-regexp</kbd>

   - For the matching regexp, use `\([[:digit:]]+\)`.
   - For the replacement, use `\,(format "%X" (string-to-number \1))`.

**B.**

1. Mark the region containing the numbers.
2. Type <kbd>C-x * g</kbd>.
3. Type <kbd>V R +</kbd>.
4. Type <kbd>y</kbd> to insert the sum, or <kbd>C-u y</kbd> to replace.

**C.**

Same as for **A**, but mark just the last number, and use a replacement function of `\,(format "%s\n%d" \1 (1+ (string-to-number \1)))`.

You can put these in macros or functions which take care of moving point around to the right place.

Comment: Good Answer. Need upcase "G" for grabbing region: "C-x * G"

Comment: No need for (format "%s\n%d" \1 (1+ (string-to-number \1))), a short (+ x \#1) would do the job as "#1" automatically converts the match into a number